# Why would calling cd (builtin) from cd (shell function) without "command" cause an endless loop?

Tags: bash, command, cd-command, syntax, bash-functions

I once read in a Bash book by O'Reilly the following (my summary):

#### command and enable

```
cd () {
    echo "Improved CD !"
    # Improvement one;
    command cd
    # Improvement two;
    # Do cool stuff...
}
cd
```

> The command `command` is useful when a function containing a builtin
>   is identically named as that builtin - it prevents recursive loop of
>   the builtin in the function;

My question here is why would there be a recursive loop in the first place if we call the function just once?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you try

```
cd () {
    echo "Improved CD !"
    # Improvement one;
    cd
    # Improvement two;
    # Do cool stuff...
}
cd
```

*without* `command`, `cd` will call the `cd` function, which will call the `cd` function, which will call the `cd` function, and so on:  the `cd` statement inside the function calls the `cd` function, not the `cd` built-in. You’ll see “Improved CD !” repeated ad nauseam in your terminal.

The ultimate result will vary depending on the shell: Zsh will stop (“maximum nested function level reached”), Bash will crash.